# How to parse Hexcode of Network traffic

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, hex

First of all, thanks to the community of Stack Overflow. I've found lots of competent answers here, so I'll try to ask my own question.

I have a WinPcap sample  program which "dumps" my network traffic as Hexcode.
I made a simple server/client pair which periodically sends some text (22 bytes).

**Problem:**
Parsing this Hex-dump in C++ and generate an output like Wireshark or phd does (just in the console).

After reading some TCP/IP references (1), I'm not able to determine all bytes "values"
So for example there are 76 bytes, reading backwards:

- the first 22 bytes are my Data;
- then, there are 20 for the TCP header;
- 20 for the IP Header and then some other Bytes I don't know what they stand for. I'm not very knowledgeable about the IP protocol.

Here is an example in hex:

```
08 00 27 b3 23 63 f4 6d 04 2e 68 24 08 00 45 00
00 3e 31 c4 40 00 80 06 45 9e c0 a8 01 03 c0 a8
01 04 0b 27 04 d2 b0 f7 47 61 28 6c fd a7 50 18
fa f0 8e a0 00 00 48 61 6c 6c 6f 20 64 61 73 20
69 73 74 20 65 69 6e 20 54 65 73 74
```

**Question:**
Can someone tell me what these first bytes are for, and
where to get a (simple) description of how the network traffic is composed?

(1) [TCP Reference](http://www.netfor2.com/tcp.htm), [IP Reference](http://www.netfor2.com/ip.htm)

Comment: if it's give you a hex of structure of tcp ,create a tcp structure and map your data to it.use your dump library structures for cleaning the packet data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Packet Dump Decode](http://code.google.com/p/pdd/) and decoded this into the following data... `pdd` translates the the hex dump into something you can use in wireshark... then I worked backwards from the wireshark info to break the packet down...

```
Ethernet Header
---------------
08 00 27 b3 23 63 f4 6d 04 2e 68 24 08 00 

IP Header
---------
45 00 00 3e 31 c4 40 00 80 06 45 9e 
c0 a8 01 03 c0 a8 01 04

TCP Header
----------
0b 27 04 d2 b0 f7 47 61 28 6c fd a7 50 18
fa f0 8e a0 00 00

TCP Data Payload
----------------
48 61 6c 6c 6f 20 64 61 73 20
69 73 74 20 65 69 6e 20 54 65 73 74
```

And a full wireshark decode...

```
Frame 1: 76 bytes on wire (608 bits), 76 bytes captured (608 bits)
    WTAP_ENCAP: 1
    Arrival Time: Nov 24, 2012 07:12:54.000000000 Central Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1353762774.000000000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
    Frame Length: 76 bytes (608 bits)
    Capture Length: 76 bytes (608 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:tcp:data]
Ethernet II, Src: AsustekC_2e:68:24 (f4:6d:04:2e:68:24), Dst: CadmusCo_b3:23:63 (08:00:27:b3:23:63)
    Destination: CadmusCo_b3:23:63 (08:00:27:b3:23:63)
        Address: CadmusCo_b3:23:63 (08:00:27:b3:23:63)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: AsustekC_2e:68:24 (f4:6d:04:2e:68:24)
        Address: AsustekC_2e:68:24 (f4:6d:04:2e:68:24)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3), Dst: 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 62
    Identification: 0x31c4 (12740)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x459e [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3)
    Destination: 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: msrp (2855), Dst Port: search-agent (1234), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 22
    Source port: msrp (2855)
    Destination port: search-agent (1234)
    [Stream index: 0]
    Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 23    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set
        .... .... 1... = Push: Set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
    Window size value: 64240
    [Calculated window size: 64240]
    [Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)]
    Checksum: 0x8ea0 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [Bytes in flight: 22]
Data (22 bytes)

0000  48 61 6c 6c 6f 20 64 61 73 20 69 73 74 20 65 69   Hallo das ist ei
0010  6e 20 54 65 73 74                                 n Test
    Data: 48616c6c6f20646173206973742065696e2054657374
    [Length: 22]
```

Comment: Ethernet Header... cutting that of (always the first 14 bytes?) it worked. Thanks for the fast help!

Comment: The length of Ethernet headers is at least 14 bytes, assuming you got the full headers passed to you from the ethernet driver.  The challenge is that some drivers pass things differently... the other challenge is that ethernet may have more information (such as a dot1q field) that makes the header longer